# How to read this problem from Dummit-Foote's "Abstract Algebra"?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Problem 14.6.1 on page 617 says

> Show that a cubic with a multiple root has a linear factor. Is the same true for quartics?

Let $f \in F[x]$ be a cubic. If $f$ has a root in $F$, let alone a multiple root in $F$, then it has a linear factor in $F[x]$. So, I suppose we should really be assuming that $f$ has a multiple root in an extension field $E \supseteq F$. Obviously $f$ has a linear factor in $E[x]$, so I suppose we should be arguing that $f$ has a linear factor in $F[x]$.  But, I don't think that is even true. Consider $f(x) = x^3 - t$ in $F_3(t)[x]$. This has a root of multiplicity $3$ in the splitting field, but no root in $F_3(t)$, right?

This problem is discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/572344/cubic-with-repeated-roots-has-a-linear-factor), but I wondered if anyone had a suggestion for how to interpret this problem, so that the question becomes sensible.

Comment: Consider $(x^2+1)^2$ for $F$ the real numbers.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks, but that's not really what I'm asking about. My point is that the first part of the question seems broken, and I was wondering if it can be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual meaning of “having a multiple root” includes “in some extension field”. I can only interpret “has a linear factor” assuming “in $F[x]$” or it would make no sense.

I don't have Dummit-Foote available, so I guess that the exercise has some context, because the statement can be false in case the field has characteristic $3$.

A polynomial $f(x)\in F[x]$ has a multiple root (in some extension field) if and only if $f$ and $f'$ (the formal derivative) have a common factor. This can be checked by just working over $F$, because the greatest common divisor can be computed with the Euclidean algorithm.

The statement is true provided $F$ doesn't have characteristic $3$. Indeed, your example is good: the polynomial $x^3-t$ with coefficients in the field of rational functions $\mathbb{F}_3(t)$ has a multiple root in $\mathbb{F}_3(\sqrt[3]{t})$ because it factors as $(x-\sqrt[3]{t})^3$, but has no linear factor in $\mathbb{F}_3(t)$.

If the characteristic is not $3$, the derivative of a cubic polynomial is not $0$; so if $g=\gcd(f,f')\ne 1$, it has degree $1$ or $2$. In the case $\deg g=1$, we found a linear factor of $f$. In the case $\deg g=2$, $f/g$ is a linear factor.

For the quartic case, consider $(x^2+1)^2$, with $F$ the real field.

Comment: It looks like you and A. Nicolas have answered in the same way at around the same time. I'll select your answer I suppose, because of the greater level of detail. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

If the cubic $f$ has a multiple root in some extension field  $E$, and $F$ **does not** have characteristic $3$, then the cubic and its derivative have a common root in the extension field, so they are not relatively prime in that field.

It follows $f$ and $f'$ are not relatively prime in $F$. If $f'$ divides $f$, then $f$ has a linear factor. If $f'$ does not divide $f$, then they have a linear gcd, and again $f$ has a root in $F$.

Comment: OK, so we can just assume characteristic not equal to three to get a reasonable question. Very elegant proof by the way!

Comment: I skipped a bit of theory. If they were relatively prime over $F$, then (Bezout) some linear combination with coefficients polynomials in $F[x]$ would be equal to $1$, so they would be linearly independent over $E$.

Comment: No problem, I'm comfortable with those details which you skipped :)